# Why did the frequency of TLEs for the Hubble Space Telescope drop by a factor of 3 in 2009?

Tags: hubble, two-line-elements

I noticed that the [TLEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) for the [Hubble Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Space_Telescope) (HST) are posted almost twice a day. Then I looked back in time and saw that this rate varies quite a lot!

The plot **shows the time interval between consecutive TLEs (in days)** for the HST in [space-track.org](https://www.space-track.org). The blue line is all points and the black line is a rolling average of 100 points. It seems to suddenly jump from about 0.7 day to 2 days between TLEs in May 2009 (JD ~ 2,454,960) , then slowly increase in frequency, until August 2015 when it drops back down to about 0.7 days (JD ~ 2,457,285).

Do these changes (and this pattern) reflect anything of significance? Budget cuts? Shifts in Observing Program requirements? [USSTRATCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Strategic_Command) busy?

Data from 2000-01-01 to present:

### These plots are intervals (days) between successive TLEs, *not TLEs/day*

[image: HST mean time between TLEs]

**CLICK TO EXPAND**

[image: HST mean time between TLEs by year]

Comment: Can you post a graph with the x-axis labelled by date?

Comment: @Steve python is supposed to be easy - so I'll give it a try... but plotting in python is not so pleasant. There is a tick every month, and you can see that the transitions are in the months already indicated in the text of the question. The terms of space-track don't allow me to post the data (which would be easier for everyone).

Comment: Does this happen only for Hubble, or for other satellites in the database as well?

Comment: @2012rcampion Thanks! I was holding my breath hoping someone closer to the HST might actually know the answer before I'd have to do look into that. There are a whole lot of objects tracked - if you can suggest a few that you think would make for the most relevant comparison, I can check those.

Comment: @uhoh, I'd use the ISS (roughly similar orbit, and likely to be heavily tracked), USA-132 (the oldest operational GPS satellite, likely to be heavily tracked), and a randomly-selected upper stage (to get a baseline for "minimal resources spent tracking something").

Comment: I'm stumped by this: the decrease in frequency coincides with the last to servicing missions. Maybe they were more confident after the reboost?

Comment: @Ludo that sounds like a good-enough partial answer to post - oh I just noticed that you'd posted something! Why not edit it and undelete?

Comment: @uhoh ok, let's see if it can be expanded. Maybe one of our resident STS experts knows more...

Answer (score 3):

There were 5 servicing missions to HST:

- Servicing Mission 1 in December 1993
- Servicing Mission 2 in February 1997
- Servicing Mission 3A in December 1999
- Servicing Mission 3B in March 2002
- Servicing Mission 4 in May 2009

The decrease in tracking frequencies in your plot coincide with SM 3B and SM4. At the end of each mission HST was boosted up to a higher orbit to counter orbital decay. Perhaps the confidence in the orbital parameters after the reboost was sufficiently high to warrant a lower update frequency for a while.